# Creating Webservice which has child parent concept

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I want to create web service as below. i get result as list for 1 people, but i just want common things as it's parent and have many child i.e. Detail in it's child level.

```
  <person>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>Manoj</name>
     <age>20</age>
     <salary>
      <month>1</month>
      <money>10000</money>
     </salary>
     <salary>
      <month>2</month>
      <money>12000</money>
     </salary>
     <salary>
      <month>3</month>
      <money>13000</money>
     </salary>
    </person>
```

but my web service return as

```
<person>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>Manoj</name>
     <age>20</age>     
     <month>1</month>
     <money>10000</money>
</person>

<person>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>Manoj</name>
     <age>20</age>     
     <month>2</month>
     <money>12000</money>
</person>

<person>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>Manoj</name>
     <age>20</age>     
     <month>2</month>
     <money>13000</money>
</person>
```

my info class is

```
class person 
{
    int id{get; set;}
    string name{get; set;}
    int age{get; set;}
    int month{get; set;}
    int money{get; set;}
}
```

how can i modyfy class to get rusult.

Comment: create a class called persons that has a constructor to generate a collection object of type person

Comment: @Sanpopo i am confused . object of type person or salary.

Comment: I guess it depends what you want, if you don't want a person node for every person, then go with the salary class, if you want one node of persons containing a node for each person (this would make sense to me) then a collection object of type person could be used... I am assuming this is for a homework assignment??

Comment: @Sanpopo here 1 person have same attribute with different value i.e. manoj have difeernt salary for differnt month

Comment: so then you probably want to do what Erin suggested and have salary class

Answer (score 1):

You could try modifying your `Person` class to include a collection of `Salaeries`

```
public class person 
{
    public int id{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
    public int age{get; set;}
    public List<Salary> Salaeries {get; set;}
}

public class Salary
{
    int month{get; set;}
    int money{get; set;}
}
```

This was also suggested in comments

Comment: Than you it help me so much. I am getting result by query `select id,name,age,month,money from person group by id` and it assign values to my info but how can i assign values to this class Person. @JensKloster

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to create a salary class that contains the salary attributes (money, month) and a salary property (an array) on your person class. The format won't be exactly what you asked for, but close.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make both parent and child class
In Parent class you will keep the information that is common. Like- name, age, sex
In child class you will keep the information that is repetitive. Like month , salary, bonus, incentive, commission, extra hour pay, night duty double pay etc.

Now when you bind your info, then you need to fill that Salary class list with the result from database.
Hope, this helps you to solve problem and doubles your salary